# How do I format a print statement to print to a certain number of decimal points?

Tags: formatting, python-3.3

I'm trying to write a program in python 3.3 that will enable a ice hockey goaltender to be able to calculate his goals against average and save percentage. 
GAA usually appears in this format:

```
        1.50
```

And Save Percentage is displayed in the following format:

```
        0.927
```

With that in mind, here is my code so far:

```
  Goals_Against = input("Enter Number of Goals Allowed: ")
  Games_Played = input("Enter Number of Games Played: ")
  Shots_Faced = input("Enter Number of Shots Faced: ")
  Shots_Saved = input("Enter Number of Shots Saved: ")      

  def GoalsAgainstAverage():
       GAA = (int(Goals_Against) / int(Games_Played))
       print("Your Goals Against Average is:",GAA)
       format(GAA, '.2f')
  def main():
      GoalsAgainstAverage()

  main()
```

After I enter in, for example, 12 as the input for Goals_Against and 8 as the input for Games_Played, it always prints in the following format:

```
  1.5
```

Why is it not displaying as 1.50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
print("Your Goals Against Average is:", "{0:.2f}".format(GAA))
```

Comment: Great glad I could help you out, welcome to the forum! If you are satisfied with the answer please do accept it for the ratings. THANKS!